# How to stop refresh Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, asp.net

I am using Subgurim.Controles google maps in my project,i was updating every 40 with new marker to the Gmap.

I just want to update position of marker every 40 seconds, not refresh entire Gmap. Here i am using timer for every 40 sec to get new latlng from database table;

aspx code:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
             </asp:Timer>
             <div id="map">
             cc1:GMap ID="GMap1" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" />
             </div>
```

C# code:

```
  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  GMap1.resetMarkers(); Subgurim.Controles.GLatLng gLatLng = new
    > Subgurim.Controles.GLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(status.Rows[0][0]),
    > Convert.ToDouble(status.Rows[0][1])); GMap1.setCenter(gLatLng, 16,
    > Subgurim.Controles.GMapType.GTypes.Normal); Subgurim.Controles.GMarker
    > oMarker = new Subgurim.Controles.GMarker(gLatLng);
    > GMap1.addGMarker(oMarker); }
```